# Creating a Table in SQL, where each tuple can have mutiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, create-table

I m try to make a Table using Create Table in SQL,
where a person can work at multiple places, and a place can have multiple person working on it,
this is what i m trying, i m sure its not correct

```
      create table ( person char(15), place char(15), salary int)
```

now since a person can work in multiple places, i m confused should the tuple place has multiple values,
if yes. how do i do it 
Thanks in advance

Comment: for future reference: a tuple in Relational DB *can never* have a varying number of columns. That's part of the fundamental structure for a Relational DB -- there are a certain number of columns for a table and no tuple in that table will have a different number of columns.

Comment: Unrelated but: you most probably do **not** want to use `char(xxx)`. That datatype gets padded with spaces to the defined length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create three separate tables:

```
"persons"
int ID (primary key, auto-increment)
varchar username
varchar email ... (all other info needed)

"places"
int ID (primary key, auto-increment)
varchar name
etc.
```

And the third table gives you the relationship between the two:

```
"person_places" (or place_persons, depends on what you like)
int ID (primary key, auto-increment)
int place_id (linked to the ID of the "places" entry)
int person_id (linked to the ID of the "persons" entry)
```

This way, every time a person starts working in a new place, you just add an entry to the "person_places". Same thing when they leave a place, or a place goes out of business or whatever, you just need to touch the "person_places" table.

Also, this way, one person can work in several places, just like one place can have several people working in it.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a *n to m relation*. Use 3 tables

```
persons table
-------------
id    int
name  varchar


places table
------------
id    int
name  varchar


place_persons table
-------------------
place_id   int
person_id  int
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not normalized but it is ok to use this as you have only 3 columns and normalization will add more headache of joins and extra columns to define relationship.

suppose PersonA works in both PlaceA and PlaceB. PersonB also works in both the places but on different salaries then your data will be like this

```
insert into Yourtable values 
('PersonA','PlaceA',1000),
('PersonA','PlaceB',2000),
('PersonB','PlaceA',1100),
('PersonB','PlaceB',1200),
('PersonC','PlaceA',1000)
```

and if you want to know that how many places PersonA works then you query will be

```
select place from YourTable where person = 'PersonA'
```

This way you don't need to save multiple values in same tuple.